# How to share Android App with an ID

Tags: android, share, google-play

I'm looking for a way to give mobile users the ability to share an Android App along with an ID.

Now I know how to share an App and customize a text for that, but is there any way we can have query strings (or similar) in the Android Market which will be passed to our Apps when installing from there?

Basically what I'd like to do is to have someone's ID to be sent with the App whenever they share it, and once the other user clicks the link with the ID parameter from the market, to download the App and have the ID of the person who shared embedded within the App for marketing purposes.

[HeyTell App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.heytell&hl=en) has this sort of feature but they share the name of the user who shared the App instead of an ID.